# Unable to install Radium using npm comand

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, radium

**Command**

```
npm install --save radium
```

**Error**

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-complete-guid-1@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from radium@0.26.2
npm ERR! node_modules/radium
npm ERR!   radium@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.    

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-09T12_51_53_580Z-debug-0.log
```

Note: I am trying to install radium but this error is showing. I don't know why.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to remove your `node_modules` and run `npm install` again, it's a common problem that something went wrong with the installation.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install --save radium --force
```

This command will remove `node_modules` and then install the dependencies from your `package.json` file and install **radium** library.